# Maximum permuted row/column sum of a matrix

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

Given a real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ (feel free to assume its entries are non-negative, if it helps), what is known about the problem of computing the quantity
$$
\max_{\sigma \in S_n} \left\{\sum_{j=1}^na_{j,\sigma(j)}\right\}?
$$
(Here $S_n$ is the symmetric group, so we are maximizing over all permutations of the columns of $A$: if you like you can write the sum as $\mathrm{trace}(AP_\sigma)$, where $P_\sigma$ is the permutation matrix associated with the permutation $\sigma$).

For example, is it known to be NP-hard, or is there a known polynomial-time algorithm for computing it (maybe just for certain special classes of matrices)? Does it have a name and/or is it equivalent to a well-known problem? It feels vaguely graph isomorphism-ish to me, but I'm having trouble pinning it down.

As one minor note, numerical examples show that the greedy algorithm (i.e., pick the largest entry of $A$, then forget about that row and column and pick the largest entry of the remaining $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix, and repeat) does not always produce the maximum value even if $A$ is doubly stochastic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the maximum weight matching problem in the weighted complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$, also known as the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). It does have a few polynomial-time algorithmic solutions.

Comment: There was a recent theoretical breakthrough: [Maximum Flow and Minimum-Cost Flow in Almost-Linear Time](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.00671) by Chen et al. But I don't know if this work translates into practical improvements in running time.